# Compare 4 dates with Workflow 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow

Folks ,

I have SharePoint 2010 Workflow that needs to send 4 different notifications based on 4 dates(variables) happened . How to get the nearest date then longer then longer ? How to make this comparison so I can use pause .

Answer (score 0):

In either Designer or Visual Studio Create a function or reusable/custom activity that you pass x number of dates to and it passes back either the highest or lowest date which you then assign to a variable.

You can either do DateChecker(date1,date2,date3,date4, high/low) or DateCheckerHigh(date1,date2,date3,date4) and DateCheckerLow(date1,date2,date3,date4)

If you're only going to use it once, you can just do all of it inline in your workflow.